DoqueDBでPython環境がインストールできない
UNIXに関しては中途半端な知識しか持たない者ですが，KJ法のようなことをパソコン上でおこなうシステムを開発しようと考えています。DoqueDBはそのような用途にちょうど適していると思い，インストールしてみています。
とりあえず，SQLとJavaでサンプルを実行するところまではうまくいったのですが，「Pythonでサンプルを実行する」がうまくいきません。
pip3 install py_doquedb-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
を実行しても，sydney/Python というディレクトリができず(どこにできるのかもわからない)，そこから先に進めません。
どこが悪いのかをご教示いただければ幸いです。

ご利用ありがとうございます。中のものです。
説明が不足しておりましたが、Pythonクライアントのインストールは
DoqueDBのGitHubリポジトリが手元にあることを前提としています。
git clone https://github.com/DoqueDB/doquedb
として、リポジトリをローカルにクローンしてきてください。
(バイナリパッケージとの位置関係に制約はありません。
どこか作業できそうな場所に置いていただければけっこうです。)
sydney/Pythonはその中にあります。
https://github.com/DoqueDB/doquedb/blob/master/sydney/Python/README_ja.md
ご不便お掛けして申し訳ありません。
ドキュメントは後日訂正させていただきます。

ご回答ありがとうございます。すでにそのようにしてPython環境の試用には成功しております。

無事お使いいただけたようで幸いです。
今後もよろしくお願い申し上げます。

またいろいろ質問するかもしれませんがよろしくお願いしますm(__)m

はい。質問お待ちしております。

pip でインストールしているのはあくまで DopueDB を Python から操作するためのライブラリをインストールしているに過ぎません。
恐らくはSQL と Java のサンプルと同様、 https://github.com/DoqueDB/doquedb からダウンロードしたアーカイブを展開したディレクトリの中に sydney/Python のサブディレクトリが含まれているはずなのでよく確認してください。
https://github.com/DoqueDB/doquedb/blob/master/sydney/Python/README_ja.md

ありがとうございます！公式のインストールパッケージには入ってなかったのですが，githubからは落とせました。これで何とかしてみます。
